# Most efficient way with Pandas to check pair of values from 2 series?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a series/dataframe `A` that looks like

```
A = [3,2,1,5,4,...
```

`A` could also be sorted as it doesn't matter to me. I want to create a new series that keeps track of possible pairs. That is, I want the result to look like

```
B = [3_1, 3_2, 3_4, ..., 2_1, 2_4, ..., 1_4, 1_5,...
```

That is, I want to exclude `2_3`, since `3_2` already exists. I figure I could create each element in `B` using something like

```
for i in A:
    for j in A:
        s = A[i].astype(str) + '_' + A[j].astype(str)
        B.append(pd.Series([s]))
```

But I'm not sure how to make sure the (i,j) pairing doesn't already exist, such as making sure `2_3` doesn't get added as I mentioned above

What is the most efficient way to deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
s2 = pd.Series("_".join([str(a), str(b)]) for a, b in combinations(s, 2))

>>> s2
0    1_2
1    1_3
2    1_4
3    2_3
4    2_4
5    3_4
dtype: object
```

Comment: I don't really see how this addresses the "no duplications" part of the question, I must say.

Comment: Notice there is 1_2 but no 2_1.  That's what combinations does.

Comment: However, the original list might contain duplicates, no?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that is what the OP was referring to (" I want to exclude 2_3, since 3_2 already exists").  If not, it is easy enough to fix with `combinations(s.unique(), 2)`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this really has much to do with pandas, except for the values originating (and possibly ending) in a series. Instead, I'd use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Say you have an iterable `a` of values. Then

```
import itertools

set((str(i) + '_' + str(j)) for (i, j) in itertools.product(a, a) if i <= j)
```

will create a set of pairs where the integer before the `_` is not larger than that after that, removing duplicates.

---

**Example**

```
import itertools

>>> set((str(i) + '_' + str(j)) for (i, j) in itertools.product(a, a) if i < j)
{'1_2',
 '1_3',
 '1_4',
 '1_6',
 '1_7',
 '2_3',
 '2_4',
 '2_6',
 '2_7',
 '3_4',
 '3_6',
 '3_7',
 '4_6',
 '4_7',
 '6_7'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
>>> [(str(x)+'_'+str(y)) for x in a for y in a if y>x]
['3_5', '3_4', '2_3', '2_5', '2_4', '1_3', '1_2', '1_5', '1_4', '4_5']
```

Note that the ordering of the members in the pairs in the result is sorted because of the `y>x` statement, which is why we have `'1_3'` in our output instead of `'3_1'`.

While importing itertools and using combinations is a correct way to do this, I usually prefer not to import libraries if I only need one one or two things from them that can also be easily accomplished via direct means.